# MongoDB find in array in all documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents with this simplified structure:

```
{
   cards: [
       {
           id: "some string",
           ....
       },{...}{...}{...}
   ]
}
```

I need to query the whole collection of documents and find those documents where my defined ID of a card matches one of the objects in the array of cards.

I usually fetch all documents and do it locally but this is quite large collection and I have no clue how to achieve this if even possible.

Thank you for your time!

ps: I'm using nodejs mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with mohammad Naimi's solution I figured the correct syntax:

db.collection.find({ cards:{ $elemMatch: { id: { $eq:"some string" }}}})

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({cards:{$elemMatch:{id:{$eq:"some string"}}})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick response but it doesn't work for me for some reason. (youre missing one } but I added it) https://prnt.sc/1rhjnbp after hitting enter it says 0 matches. I tried in my app too and no luck.